# Use a Javascript variable in CSS to control the visibility of the object

Tags: javascript, html, css, visibility

I have made a table using Javascript, and stored the table in a variable that I can refer to in CSS. In the CSS, I want to hide the table, by referring to the table's Javascript variable. It sounds extremely confusing... This is what I mean:

Here is the code for the table 1:

```
grid1=display_array(array1);
```

The display_array function creates a table in javascript, and automatically displays it into the HTML.

After 30 seconds, I want to hide grid 1 and show grid 2. So I assume I must use this syntax for the timer:

```
setTimeout(function(){grid2=display_array(array2);//Which automatically shows the grid2
                      //syntax for hiding grid1
                      },30000);
```

Do I need to hide the table using CSS and refer to its Javascript variable in CSS? If so, how do I do that?

Or as an alternative, can I just control the visibility of the table using only Javascipt?

Much appreciated.

Comment: You can control the visibility of any dom element using javascript through setting its display style

Comment: if grid1 is aDOM-Element, you can do `grid1.style.display='none';` if not, give it an ID and go by `document.getElementById("idOfGrid1").style.display='none';`

Comment: You can have a CSS class that hides/shows it and add/remove that class using the JS outlined here: http://www.kirupa.com/snippets/add_class_and_remove_class_snippet.htm 
You'd be better using jquery for this though. 
You can also do as Mr.Manhatten and Rakesh_Kumar suggest

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in javascript interval

If your table one have a ID " tbl1 "
and table two with " tbl2 "

```
function onload() 
{
  setTimeout(function() 
  {
    table_one = document.getElementById("tbl1");
    table_two = document.getElementById("tbl2");

    if(table_one.style.display == "none")
    {
       table_one.style.display = "block";
       table_two.style.display = "none";
    }
    else
    {
       table_one.style.display = "none";
       table_two.style.display = "block";
    }
  }, 3000); //Seconds you want to set for this
}
```

Set one table display=none by default.

Comment: My table is created in javascript, so it is not coded in the HTML; hence it doesn't have an id, it only has a javascript variable.

Comment: @Stephen Gevanni You can ad an id attribute to any html element (as table) the same you do with others as style, type, etc.